# Bootstrap in WebView crashing on iOS 9 (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap-3, uiwebview, ios9, xcode7

I have an app which contains a `WebView` using Bootstrap. The app previously worked fine on iOS 8 & 9 when compiled with Xcode 6 and Swift 1.2, but having upgraded to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0, for some reason the app keeps crashing.

Curiously, I have traced the cause of the crash to the inclusion of `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in my HTML in the WebView (the HTML file, along with `bootstrap.min.css` is loaded locally from the app bundle). As soon as I comment-out the `<link>` tag, it works fine.

The backtrace I get is as follows:

```
* thread #16: tid = 0xa95c2, 0x00000001975927d4 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw, name = 'WebThread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2
  * frame #0: 0x00000001975927d4 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw
    frame #1: 0x000000018cf38728 libType1Scaler.dylib`TType1LWFNMultipleMasterHFMXTable::TType1LWFNMultipleMasterHFMXTable(TFontObjectSurrogate const&, int, short, short, int*) + 132
    frame #2: 0x000000018cf38638 libType1Scaler.dylib`TType1LWFNFont::CreateHFMXTable() const + 96
    frame #3: 0x000000018cf385c4 libType1Scaler.dylib`TType1HFMXTableSurrogate::TType1HFMXTableSurrogate(TType1PSFont const&) + 48
    frame #4: 0x000000018cf37e6c libType1Scaler.dylib`TType1PSFont::GetFontInstanceSpec(TType1Transform const&, FixedPoint&, FixedPoint&, FixedPoint&, FixedPoint&, FixedPoint&, FixedRectangle&, FontMetrics&) const + 520
    frame #5: 0x000000018cf37bdc libType1Scaler.dylib`TType1Strike::GetSpecs(StrikeSpecs&) const + 112
    frame #6: 0x000000018cf31584 libType1Scaler.dylib`Type1GetStrikeSpecs(unsigned int, TStrikeDescription const*, StrikeSpecs*) + 48
    frame #7: 0x000000018ce34bc0 libFontParser.dylib`TConcreteFontScaler::GetFontInfo(FPFontInfo*) const + 60
    frame #8: 0x000000018ce0eea4 libFontParser.dylib`TFPFont::FillFontInfo(TFPFontInfo&) const + 200
    frame #9: 0x000000018ce0ed90 libFontParser.dylib`TFPFont::GetFontInfo() const + 56
    frame #10: 0x000000018ce0ed4c libFontParser.dylib`FPFontIsMonospaced + 12
    frame #11: 0x00000001836cd468 libCGXType.A.dylib`get_font_info + 56
    frame #12: 0x000000018356e314 CoreGraphics`get_font_info + 72
    frame #13: 0x00000001835717e4 CoreGraphics`CGFontGetNumberOfGlyphs + 12
    frame #14: 0x0000000183ddb7f4 CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyGraphicsFont() const + 52
    frame #15: 0x0000000183e8b500 CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyTable(unsigned int) const + 212
    frame #16: 0x0000000183ddf4ac CoreText`TBaseFont::GetCmapTable() const + 60
    frame #17: 0x0000000183ddf284 CoreText`TBaseFont::GetUnicodeEncoding() const + 64
    frame #18: 0x0000000183e86e54 CoreText`TBaseFont::GetUnicodeCmapSubHeader(void const**) const + 40
    frame #19: 0x0000000183de1074 CoreText`TBaseFont::CopyCharacterSet() const + 212
    frame #20: 0x0000000183e0b3c0 CoreText`TBaseFont::GetCharacterSetInternal() const + 44
    frame #21: 0x0000000183e48ac4 CoreText`CompareCharSet(__CFCharacterSet const*, TBaseFont const*) + 24
    frame #22: 0x0000000183e00260 CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorsForRequestFromArray(__CFArray const*, __CFDictionary const*, CFComparisonResult (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long, bool) const + 1040
    frame #23: 0x0000000183e4c7a0 CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorsForRequest(__CFDictionary const*, __CFSet const*, CFComparisonResult (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long, TCFRef<__CFArray const*>*) const + 2044
    frame #24: 0x0000000183e4bcb4 CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopySystemWideFallbackDescriptorForCharacters(TBaseFont const&, unsigned short const*, long, UIFontFlag, TCFRef<__CFArray const*>*) const + 616
    frame #25: 0x0000000183e8b0c4 CoreText`TBaseFont::CreateDescriptorForCharacters(__CFArray const*, UIFontFlag, unsigned short const*, long, long&) const + 360
    frame #26: 0x0000000183e3a850 CoreText`TFont::InitDescriptor(TFont const&, unsigned short const*, long, __CFString const*, long&) + 328
    frame #27: 0x0000000183e31b10 CoreText`CTFontCreatePhysicalFontDescriptorForCharactersWithLanguage + 144
    frame #28: 0x0000000195262478 WebCore`WebCore::FontCache::systemFallbackForCharacters(WebCore::FontDescription const&, WebCore::Font const*, bool, unsigned short const*, unsigned int) + 356
    frame #29: 0x000000019525eaa4 WebCore`WebCore::Font::systemFallbackFontForCharacter(int, WebCore::FontDescription const&, bool) const + 528
    frame #30: 0x000000019526d920 WebCore`WebCore::FontCascadeFonts::glyphDataForSystemFallback(int, WebCore::FontDescription const&, WebCore::FontVariant) + 100
    frame #31: 0x000000019526e76c WebCore`WebCore::FontCascadeFonts::glyphDataForCharacter(int, WebCore::FontDescription const&, WebCore::FontVariant) + 772
    frame #32: 0x0000000194e042e0 WebCore`unsigned int WebCore::WidthIterator::advanceInternal<WebCore::SurrogatePairAwareTextIterator>(WebCore::SurrogatePairAwareTextIterator&, WebCore::GlyphBuffer*) + 564
    frame #33: 0x0000000194e0408c WebCore`WebCore::WidthIterator::advance(int, WebCore::GlyphBuffer*) + 136
    frame #34: 0x0000000195265770 WebCore`WebCore::FontCascade::floatWidthForSimpleText(WebCore::TextRun const&, WTF::HashSet<WebCore::Font const*, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::Font const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::Font const*> >*, WebCore::GlyphOverflow*) const + 248
    frame #35: 0x0000000195265634 WebCore`WebCore::FontCascade::width(WebCore::TextRun const&, WTF::HashSet<WebCore::Font const*, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::Font const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::Font const*> >*, WebCore::GlyphOverflow*) const + 396
    frame #36: 0x0000000195983e48 WebCore`WebCore::RenderText::computePreferredLogicalWidths(float, WTF::HashSet<WebCore::Font const*, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::Font const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::Font const*> >&, WebCore::GlyphOverflow&) + 1532
    frame #37: 0x0000000194ec893c WebCore`WebCore::RenderText::computePreferredLogicalWidths(float) + 48
    frame #38: 0x0000000194ec8294 WebCore`WebCore::RenderText::trimmedPrefWidths(float, float&, bool&, float&, bool&, bool&, bool&, float&, float&, float&, float&, bool&) + 160
    frame #39: 0x00000001958a9f5c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::computeInlinePreferredLogicalWidths(WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) const + 5372
    frame #40: 0x00000001958a87dc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::computeIntrinsicLogicalWidths(WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) const + 76
    frame #41: 0x0000000194ec0e3c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::computePreferredLogicalWidths() + 336
    frame #42: 0x0000000194eb9a24 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBox::minPreferredLogicalWidth() const + 40
    frame #43: 0x00000001958a8c2c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::computeInlinePreferredLogicalWidths(WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) const + 460
    frame #44: 0x00000001958a87dc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::computeIntrinsicLogicalWidths(WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) const + 76
    frame #45: 0x0000000194ec0e3c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::computePreferredLogicalWidths() + 336
    frame #46: 0x0000000194eb9a24 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBox::minPreferredLogicalWidth() const + 40
    frame #47: 0x0000000194e18f18 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBox::computeLogicalWidthInRegionUsing(WebCore::SizeType, WebCore::Length, WebCore::LayoutUnit, WebCore::RenderBlock const*, WebCore::RenderRegion*) const + 628
    frame #48: 0x0000000194e10bdc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBox::computeLogicalWidthInRegion(WebCore::RenderBox::LogicalExtentComputedValues&, WebCore::RenderRegion*) const + 1360
    frame #49: 0x0000000194e105f8 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBox::updateLogicalWidth() + 40
    frame #50: 0x000000019589b978 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::recomputeLogicalWidth() + 60
    frame #51: 0x00000001958aa83c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 96
    frame #52: 0x0000000194e0fecc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 72
    frame #53: 0x00000001958bdca8 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutLineBoxes(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 1308
    frame #54: 0x00000001958aaba0 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 964
    frame #55: 0x0000000194e0fecc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 72
    frame #56: 0x00000001958aca5c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox&, WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::MarginInfo&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 880
    frame #57: 0x00000001958ab8a4 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlockChildren(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 496
    frame #58: 0x00000001958aab18 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 828
    frame #59: 0x0000000194e0fecc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 72
    frame #60: 0x00000001958aca5c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox&, WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::MarginInfo&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 880
    frame #61: 0x00000001958ab8a4 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlockChildren(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 496
    frame #62: 0x00000001958aab18 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 828
    frame #63: 0x0000000194e0fecc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 72
    frame #64: 0x00000001958aca5c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox&, WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::MarginInfo&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 880
    frame #65: 0x00000001958ab8a4 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlockChildren(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 496
    frame #66: 0x00000001958aab18 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 828
    frame #67: 0x0000000194e0fecc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 72
    frame #68: 0x00000001958aca5c WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox&, WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::MarginInfo&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 880
    frame #69: 0x00000001958ab8a4 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlockChildren(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 496
    frame #70: 0x00000001958aab18 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlockFlow::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 828
    frame #71: 0x0000000194e0fecc WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 72
    frame #72: 0x0000000194e6c6d4 WebCore`WebCore::RenderView::layout() + 896
    frame #73: 0x0000000194e6ace8 WebCore`WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 2832
    frame #74: 0x0000000195172c90 WebCore`WebCore::Document::updateLayoutIfDimensionsOutOfDate(WebCore::Element&, WebCore::DimensionsCheck) + 1312
    frame #75: 0x0000000194ed27fc WebCore`WebCore::Element::offsetWidth() + 40
    frame #76: 0x000000019552ca48 WebCore`WebCore::jsElementOffsetWidth(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, long long, JSC::PropertyName) + 48
    frame #77: 0x000000018495f35c JavaScriptCore`llint_slow_path_get_by_id + 1960
    frame #78: 0x0000000184da6820 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 9936
    frame #79: 0x0000000184da9f84 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24116
    frame #80: 0x0000000184da9db4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 23652
    frame #81: 0x0000000184da9db4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 23652
    frame #82: 0x0000000184da9db4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 23652
    frame #83: 0x0000000184da3f38 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 312
    frame #84: 0x0000000184cd0c84 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 180
    frame #85: 0x000000018496adc4 JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 400
    frame #86: 0x0000000184a7a37c JavaScriptCore`JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 80
    frame #87: 0x0000000194f5382c WebCore`WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 828
    frame #88: 0x0000000195233e18 WebCore`WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>&) + 696
    frame #89: 0x0000000194e60d14 WebCore`WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*) + 328
    frame #90: 0x0000000195228a50 WebCore`WebCore::EventContext::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event&) const + 112
    frame #91: 0x00000001952296cc WebCore`WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 904
    frame #92: 0x0000000194e60a80 WebCore`WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 36
    frame #93: 0x0000000194e65fe0 WebCore`WebCore::Document::finishedParsing() + 156
    frame #94: 0x0000000194e628dc WebCore`WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::prepareToStopParsing() + 172
    frame #95: 0x0000000194ea1a20 WebCore`WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::resumeParsingAfterScriptExecution() + 376
    frame #96: 0x00000001953191f4 WebCore`non-virtual thunk to WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::notifyFinished(WebCore::CachedResource*) + 100
    frame #97: 0x0000000194e9d734 WebCore`WebCore::CachedResource::checkNotify() + 284
    frame #98: 0x0000000194e9d500 WebCore`WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 1020
    frame #99: 0x0000000182a07488 CFNetwork`___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 100
    frame #100: 0x0000000182af5ad4 CFNetwork`___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 108
    frame #101: 0x0000000101635d30 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #102: 0x000000010163f47c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_invoke + 564
    frame #103: 0x00000001829f3c70 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 36
    frame #104: 0x00000001831e87ec CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    frame #105: 0x00000001829f3b54 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
    frame #106: 0x00000001829f3a14 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312
    frame #107: 0x00000001829f3840 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 68
    frame #108: 0x00000001832bc5a4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #109: 0x00000001832bbfb8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 412
    frame #110: 0x00000001832b9d38 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 724
    frame #111: 0x00000001831e8dc0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    frame #112: 0x0000000194e51aa0 WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 456
    frame #113: 0x000000019890bb3c libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 156
    frame #114: 0x000000019890baa0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 156
```

It does appear to be something wrong with the font rendering, but I'm not sure what it could be, I'm not doing anything particularly unusual, just displaying locally bundled HTML content with Bootstrap!

**UPDATE 20 OCT 15:**

I have now narrowed this down to the use of certain Glyphicons. For example `glyphicon-asterisk` and `glyphicon-user` work fine, but using `glyphicon-share-alt` causes the whole app to crash every time, with the above backtrace.

I've not managed to find a solution, other than to restrict my use of Glyphicons. Is anyone else experiencing this issue and does anyone have any suggestions?

I'm using Boostrap v3.3.5

Comment: Does the app crash for you without being attached to the debugger? I'm experiencing the same issue but it works perfectly fine when launching the app without being connected to XCode